# Is there any way to get a score (with a UDF) in all the rows of a Cassandra Partition and bring the 10 results with the highest score(ORDER BY)?

Tags: cassandra, limit, user-defined-functions, datastax-enterprise

I have got a table called users_by_group. In this table all the users that belong to the same group are stored in the same partition ordered by its user_id. Each user has 2 values, value1 and value2. I have created a user-defined-function that calculates the score of a user based on an input map variable. My problem is: I want to calculate the score of each user inside a partition but return only the 10 users with the highest score. Each partition could have more than 10000 users (rows). If I use limit 10, the score is only calculated for 10 rows inside the partition but I want to calculate it for every user inside the partition and retrieve the 10 users with the highest score. Is there another way to get my objective? The input_var map variable is different for each select statement, so it cannot be stored as a column. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_group(
     group text,
    user_id uuid,
    value1 int,
    value2 int ,
    PRIMARY KEY ((group),user_id);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION score (value1 int, value2 int, input_var map<int,float>)
            RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
            RETURNS float LANGUAGE java AS '
            return Float.valueOf(input_var.get(value1) + input_var.get(value2));';
```

```
SELECT score(value1, value2, {1:0.5, 2:1, 3: 0, 4:0.3, 5:1, 10:0}) as score, user_id FROM users_by_group  WHERE group='AA-B59'
```

Comment: why not just set it as `((group), score, user_id)` and have it ordered correctly? When score changes can do a delete and insert in new position in unlogged batch and since in same partition it will happen atomically.